# How to pass collection of variables to templates

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've been building a blog engine with flask and SqlAlchemy and I've reached a point where I have the following:

- A generic base template which has a left & right sidebar along with
  footer areas that are dynamically generated based on queries.
- A number of variables that are being passed in every view to populate said sidebars and footer.

My question is:

> Is there a means by which I can pass a group of variables to every view in a flask app without having to pass them in the `render_template()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to make a set of variables available to a template is to add them to `flask.g`.

For example, you could have `g.left_sidebars`, `g.right_sidebars` and `g.footer`, each an array with the variables that you are using. These variables could have pre-rendered HTML (maybe cached if possible to avoid rendering them every time), or they could be names of sub-templates to include.

Since `flask.g` is made available to the templates automatically all you need to do is populate these arrays during each request or in a `before_request` handler.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way of importing sidebars and other repeating elements would be to import into your layout template which is inherited by your page template. Example:

**layout.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include sidebar.html %}
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock body %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**post.html:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {{ post }}
{% endblock %}
```

You could also create a global function like this:

```
def createNav():
    nav = '''
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    '''
    return nav

#make function available inside jinja template
app.jinja_env.globals.update(createNav=createNav)
```

Then call like this:

**post.html:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {{ createNav() }}
  {{ post }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your answer is great, the app.jinja_env.globals portion will be helpful. Miguels answer, while brief, hit what I was looking for more directly. Thanks!!