# Variables in Navigation pass to base and all template in Jinja 2

Tags: python, json, templates, variables, jinja2

I have a `NavHandler` to pass json data for the nav page. I want to include the nav to the base so all the pages can see the navigation.

I can see the JSON data in `nav.html` but it does not show up in `base.html` and `index.html`.

May I know how to pass variables to all templates?

What did I miss out?

Besides that I have also followed the Jinja2 sample codes to test the on @app.context_processor and the nav.html, but given undefined variable.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount, currency=u''):
        return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(amount, currency)
    return dict(format_price=format_price)

class NavHandler(weapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        json_str = '''[{"name":"Nav A", "link":"link 1"},{"name":"Nav B", "link":"link 2"},{"name":"Nav C", "link":"link 3"}]'''
        json_data = json.load(json_str)
        template_vars = json_data

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get.template('nav.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_vars, jason_data=json=data))

class BaseHandler(weapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        template_vars = { 'title' : title}

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get.template('nav.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_vars))
```

**nav.html**

```
{% block nav %}
    <ul>
    {% for d from json_data %}
        <li><a href="{{ d.link }}">{{ d.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <script> 
            console.log({{ format_price(0.33) }});
    </script>
{ endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>{% block title %} - My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Navbar</div>
        {% include nav.html %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</h3>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors) to inject global variables in templates.

> To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template,
>   context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the
>   template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into
>   the template context.

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750655/pass-variables-to-all-jinja2-templates-with-flask) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825568), they probably can help you.

**Edit**: for the new question update

Change this line:

`return dict(format_price=g.format_price)`

for this one:

`return dict(format_price=format_price)`

Comment: So I have to import flask?

Comment: I have installed flask into app lib, then I follow the Jinja example here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors 

When I tried {{ format_price(0.33) }} in a template 'nav.html', it threw me the following error:
UndefinedError: 'format_price' is undefined.

Any idea?

Comment: @dnez no ideas without looking at the code, but for that I may suggest you to make another question focusing the scope on context processors, otherwise update the body of this question.

Comment: @dnez check the edit on the answer and see if thar works for you.

Comment: removed g. still 'UndefinedError: 'format_price' is undefined'